# angular2-mdl expansion panel with *ngFor behaves incorrectly

Tags: angular, angular2-mdl

In my component I get a list of tasks which I am showing in my template as following:

```
<mdl-expansion-panel-group>
    <mdl-expansion-panel *ngFor="let task of tasks">
        <mdl-expansion-panel-header>
            <mdl-expansion-panel-header-list-content><h6>{{task.what_task}}</h6></mdl-expansion-panel-header-list-content>
        </mdl-expansion-panel-header>
        <mdl-expansion-panel-content>
            <mdl-expansion-panel-body>

                <form [formGroup]="form">

                    <!-- What task -->
                    <p>
                        <mdl-textfield label="What task" type="text" formControlName="what_task" floating-label [ngModel]="task.what_task"></mdl-textfield>
                    </p>


                    <!-- How often -->
                    <p>
                        How often do you perform?<br/>
                        <mdl-radio value="Daily" formControlName="how_often" mdl-ripple [ngModel]="task.how_often">Daily once</mdl-radio>
                        <mdl-radio value="Weekly" formControlName="how_often" mdl-ripple [ngModel]="task.how_often">Weekly once</mdl-radio>
                    </p><br>

                    <p>
                        <button mdl-button (click)="updateTask(task, task.id)" [disabled]="!form.valid" mdl-button-type="raised" mdl-ripple mdl-colored="primary">Submit</button>
                    </p>
                </form>


            </mdl-expansion-panel-body>
        </mdl-expansion-panel-content>
    </mdl-expansion-panel>
</mdl-expansion-panel-group>
```

My idea here is that I see tasks as panels and I can expand individual panel to edit that specific task.

There are two problems I am facing here:

1. With *ngFor to iterate over task array fetched from backend expansion panel loses it's natural behavior and I am able to open all the panels (ideally only one panel is opened)
2. As I am using ngModel to bind values as received from backend for individual task I am getting `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked.` error. Which basically results in displaying last tasks properties in all the panel Forms.

What am I doing wrong here? Is it not the correct way to use expansion panels?

[image]